# What happens when params has more parameters than table columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In rails this type code automatically generated

```
@post = Post.new(params[:article_post])
@post.save
```

What happens when there are more parameters than database table columns? Say in database table we have column post_name post_id and in form I have a checkbox also along with another input field which do not need to save in database table but need for validation. In this case how the above code works. I want to know the basics.

Thanks

Comment: Have you got your answer or still have doubts.

Answer (score 1):

```
@post = Post.new(params[:article_post])
@post.save
```

Rails accepts only those parameters from request that are matched with table attributes.

For your check box validation, you can check manually like :

```
if params[:check_box_attributes_name]
  @post = Post.new(params[:article_post])
  @post.save
end
```

Comment: what if I want to do something like this '@post = Post.new(:email => "test@email.com", params[:article_post])' where I have to manually save one or two field and other fields should be filled from params

Answer (score 0):

```
@post = Post.new(params[:article_post])
@post.save
```

This code save the columns which are matched with model attributes and assign them with given values and save in the database, And columns which are posted from form but didn't have matched attributes in database will not affect the code.

Comment: what if I want to do something like this '@post = Post.new(:email => "test@email.com", params[:article_post])' where I have to manually save one or two field and other fields should be filled from params

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use Rails 3, since Rails 4 has different behavior. When you send `new`, `create`, `attributes=` or some other messages and pass a hash (and `params[:article_post]` *is* a hash), rails internally iterates through the hash and calls `#{param_name}=` method on model object. That is,

```
Post.new(:name => 'hello', :something_not_in_db => "Amazing!")
```

Is equivalent to

```
post = Post.new
post.name= 'hello'
post.something_not_in_db= "Amazing!"
```

Actually, rails first checks that all options that you pass in hash are allowed to be set with `attr_accessible`. But then it does not matter if your model table has column or not, it only matters that is responds to `attribute_name=` message

Comment: what if I want to do something like this '@post = Post.new(:email => "test@email.com", params[:article_post])' where I have to manually save one or two field  and other fields should be filled from params

Comment: Usually you first initialize object with params `post = Post.new(params[:article_post])` and then work with object directly: `post.email = "foo@bar"`. It will have same effect and more clear which params you take from form and which set manually